# How to refine that regex which skips one of two words?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a text and I want to change all *comprata, comprate, comprati, comprato* to *comprat+* and all *ricomprata, ricomprate, ricomprati, ricomprato* to *ricomprat+*. So I wrote this regex but it skips one of two words:

```
testo <- 'ricomprate uno comprato comprata due comprate ricomprate tre ricomprato comprati'
base::gsub('(\\s|^)(ri|)comprat[aeio](\\s|)', '\\1\\2comprat+\\3', testo)
```

The result is:

```
"ricomprat+ uno comprat+ comprata due comprat+ ricomprate tre ricomprat+ comprati"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not work due to the trailing `(\s|)` pattern that consumes a whitespace and prevents consecutive matches.

You can use a PCRE regex like

```r
testo <- 'ricomprate uno comprato comprata due comprate ricomprate tre ricomprato comprati'
gsub('(?<!\\S)((?:ri)?comprat)[aeio](?!\\S)', '\\1+', testo, perl=TRUE)
[1] "ricomprat+ uno comprat+ comprat+ due comprat+ ricomprat+ tre ricomprat+ comprat+"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPUVma/3). *Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `((?:ri)?comprat)` - Group 1: an optional `ri` string and then `comprat`
- `[aeio](?!\S)` - either `e`, `a`, `i` or `o` followed with right-hand whitespace boundary

Or, a TRE regex like

```r
testo <- 'ricomprate uno comprato comprata due comprate ricomprate tre ricomprato comprati'
gsub('\\b((?:ri)?comprat)[aeio]\\b', '\\1+', testo)
## => [1] "ricomprat+ uno comprat+ comprat+ due comprat+ ricomprat+ tre ricomprat+ comprat+"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/aW17y9) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5WHd6R/1), where `\b` stands for a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor! Now I understand the reason! Very clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

As a pattern you might use

```
\b((?:ri)?comprat)[aeio]\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(` Capture **group 1** (Referred to as `\\1` in the replacement)

  - `(?:ri)?` Optionally match `ri`
  - `comprat` Match `comprat`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[aeio]` Match any of the listed chars
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PMtGM9/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/jVT7Il)

In the replacement use group 1 and a `+`

```
testo <- 'ricomprate uno comprato comprata due comprate ricomprate tre ricomprato comprati'
base::gsub('\\b((?:ri)?comprat)[aeio]\\b', '\\1+', testo)
```

Output

```
[1] "ricomprat+ uno comprat+ comprat+ due comprat+ ricomprat+ tre ricomprat+ comprat+"
```

Comment: Thanks, The fourth bird! A really comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
base::gsub('comprat[aeio]', 'comprat+', testo)
```

Output

```
[1] "ricomprat+ uno comprat+ comprat+ due comprat+ ricomprat+ tre ricomprat+ comprat+"
```

Comment: Thanks, Pietro! in this case, it works. But in general, it doesn't check for the left-hand side whitespace.

Comment: You have to show a relevant minimal example and the expected output which demonstrates what you mean by that.